# How do I use Realm with generic type?

Tags: java, generics, realm

I have a generic method and would like to retrieve objects using the generic type. This is my method:

```
public static <T extends RealmObject & IndentifierModel> void storeNewData() {
  ...
  T item = realm.where(Class<T>) // Not compiling (Expression not expected)
    .equalTo("ID", data.get(i).getID())
    .findFirst();
}
```

The above isn't working for `realm.where(Class<T>)`. How do I pass in my generic type to Realm?

Answer (score 13):

You have to supply the generic parameter like so:

```
public static <T extends RealmObject & IndentifierModel> void storeNewData(Class<T> clazz) {
  T item = realm.where(clazz) 
    .equalTo("ID", 123)
    .findFirst();
}
```

`Class<T>` is not valid, since that's like saying `realm.where(Class<List<String>>)` or `realm.where(Class<String>)`. What you need is an actual [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance.   But you cannot use `T.class` either since `T` is not available at runtime due to type-erasure. At runtime, the method basically needs a `Class<T>` instance to work properly. Since you cannot get that from `T`, you will have to explicitly supply an argument of type `Class<T>`.

Comment: This could become even easier when [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761) is one day resolved.